# Flex-wrap is not wrapping when I reduce the window size

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've set up a series of three containers and applied `display: flex;` and `flex-wrap: wrap;` to them but they aren't wrapping when I reduce the window size?

I've put the code below and seem to be getting nowhere in terms of getting to the root of the problem.

```css
body {
  font-family: arial;
}

p {
  color: white;
}

.container {
  background-color: #666;
  width: 800px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.item {
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.item1 {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: red;
}

.item2 {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: blue;
}

.item3 {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="item item1">
    <h1>ITEM1</h1>
    <p>flex: 1</p>
  </div>

  <div class="item item2">
    <h1>ITEM2</h1>
    <p>flex: 1</p>
  </div>

  <div class="item item3">
    <h1>ITEM3</h1>
    <p>flex: 1</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: why would it wrap - you have not specified a width for your child items and the size of the content means they can all fit on one line, but as you have set flex to 1, it is telling the items to fit on the row as you are setting the `flex-basis` for each to be the same

Comment: Also as your container is a fixed width, the screen size will have no bearing on as to whether it wraps or not

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You need to use `max-width` instead of `width` on the container, you have to allow the container to shrink for the items to wrap.

```css
body {
  font-family: arial;
}

p {
  color: white;
}

.container {
  background-color: #666;
  max-width: 800px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.item {
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.item1 {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: red;
}

.item2 {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: blue;
}

.item3 {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="item item1">
    <h1>ITEM1</h1>
    <p>flex: 1</p>
  </div>

  <div class="item item2">
    <h1>ITEM2</h1>
    <p>flex: 1</p>
  </div>

  <div class="item item3">
    <h1>ITEM3</h1>
    <p>flex: 1</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I resized my window and everything stayed on the same line...

Comment: @Uriahs Victor You have to resize it enough so that there is not enough space for the three texts to occupy the same line, so about.

Answer (score 27):

Here's why the items aren't wrapping:

You have a flex container set to `width: 800px`.

The container has three flex items set to `flex: 1`, which is shorthand for:

- `flex-grow: 1`
- `flex-shrink: 1`
- `flex-basis: 0`

This means that the actual width of each item is `0` (`flex-basis: 0`), and each item is sized based on the available space on the line (`flex-grow: 1`).

So, in effect, you've sized each item to be one-third of the space on the line, whatever that may be. Therefore, each item can shrink to `width: 0`, and they will never wrap.

If you add content and/or `width` and/or `flex-basis` to one or more items, and the items grow to exceed 800px (the width of the container), then your flex items will wrap.

But note, they won't wrap based on your re-sizing of the browser window, because the container doesn't occupy `width: 100%` of the viewport. They will only wrap based on the width of the container.

```css
body {
  font-family: arial;
}

p {
  color: white;
}

.container {
  background-color: #666;
  width: 800px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.item {
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.item1 {
  flex: 1 0 250px;
  background-color: red;
}

.item2 {
  flex: 1 0 250px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.item3 {
  flex: 1 0 400px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="item item1">
    <h1>ITEM1</h1>
    <p>flex: 1 0 250px</p>
  </div>

  <div class="item item2">
    <h1>ITEM2</h1>
    <p>flex: 1 0 250px</p>
  </div>

  <div class="item item3">
    <h1>ITEM3</h1>
    <p>flex: 1 0 400px</p>
  </div>

</div>
```